# SQL statement to remove part of a string using a pattern

Tags: sql

I have a table column with semicolon delimited values illustrated as follows:

```
table1.ID | table1.column1 
-----------------------------------------------------
   1      | test1=aaa;test2=bbb;test3=ccc;
   2      | test1=akkaa;test2=bkjkjb;test3=cckjklc;
   3      | test1=ajaa;test2=bjhjbb;test3=sss;
```

I need to remove all `test2=xxxx` where `xxxx` can be of any value.

I started the following query which I need to complete; how I can specify a given pattern / expression?

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = Replace(column1, 'test2=', '')
WHERE column1  Is Not Null;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which RDBMS it is mysql/oracle ?

Comment: "xxxx can be of any value", could be even "xx;x" ?

Comment: I'm using a JET DB (i.e. Access)

Answer (score 1):

For MSSQL:

Try this query: (I didn't used any pattern[I don't know the possibility]. What I did is replace the string content of test2=something; with empty string. The CharIndex function is used to locate the Test2 and test3 location.)

```
 UPDATE table1 SET Column1  = 
      REPLACE(Column1, substring(Column1, CharIndex('test2=', Column1), 
           (CharIndex( 'test3=', Column1) - CharIndex('test2=', Column1))), '')
```

[--Live Demo Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cc76/1)

Answer (score 0):

for oracle:

```
update table1
set column1=substr(table1.column1,1,instr(table1.column1,';',1,1)-1)||substr(table1.column1,instr(table1.column1,';',1,2));
commit;
```